# How do I close a server with socket.io (stop it from listening to a port)

Tags: socket.io

how can I close a listener that was opened with `socket.io`
something like this:

```
io = require('socket.io').listen(3333);
```

and then at some time:

```
io.closeListener()
```

Answer (score 0):

On server side, you can do this:

```
socket.disconnect();
```

Comment: Hi 
Not sure I understand your solution. 
I am not looking to disconnect each socket seperately. I am looking for a command that disconnects all the sockets at once.

Answer (score 0):

To disconnect every client (yeah you have to go one by one):

```
for (user in io.sockets.sockets) {
    io.sockets.sockets[user].disconnect();
}
```

To close the server:

```
io.server.close();
```